# I can't view the files that are listed in the directory

Tags: php, file, dir, opendir

```
<?php 
$myDirectory = opendir("uploads");
// get each entry
while(false !== ($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))) {
if ($entryName != "." && $entryName != "..") {
    $dirArray[] = $entryName;
    }
}
// close directory
closedir($myDirectory);
//  count elements in array
$indexCount = count($dirArray);
Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n");
// sort 
sort($dirArray);
// print 
print("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class=whitelinks>\n");
print("<TR><TH>Filename</TH></TR>\n");
// loop through the array of files and print them all
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
         if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){ // don't list hidden   
         files
         print("<TR><TD><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a> 
         </td>");

        print("</TR>\n");
    }
}
print("</TABLE>\n");
?>
```

I can see the list of files but when i click any of the file , it show me object not found. 
Anyone knows what the problem in the codes?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you not open the files in right folder. Trying to give your folder front of filename. Here your code:

```
print("<TR><TD><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a>
```

And correctly is

```
print("<TR><TD><a href=\"uploads/$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a>
```

Comment: Thank you ,@Latif Rahmat .  It Worked.